# Deploying Maven module application to Glassfish

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, osgi

in first place I have to tell you that I am a newbie. I am building a simple maven based osgi application which has one jar bundle and one war bundle depending on the jar. How is the proper way to deploy the to glassfish using its autodeploy option? Will Glassfish know that the war, which is in different directory from the jar, depends on the jar and add it to its configuration? Is there something that I have to do to tell glassfish that the war file needs the jar?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In case your war is an OSGi bundle as well, you have chance. However, I guess you want to use classes from an OSGi bundle inside your traditional war. I am sorry but I do not think it is possible.

It is possible to create OSGi Web project. For example, see this tutorial: http://coding.alasdair.info/2011/01/creating-web-application-bundle-using.html

You can find many other tutorials in google.

If you made a war with OSGi Web Manifest, you must deploy it as an OSGi bundle into Glassfish to make it work as an OSGi bundle (not as an ordinary war via deploy directory)

Comment: well, the war file is maven web project, but with added MANIFEST.MF to it. So, in that case, is it ok?

Comment: edited my answer so it may give you more information to see what options you have

Comment: When I try to manually deploy jar bundle to the glassfish it says to me the following thing: "Archive type of C:\Users\Vojda\AppData\Local\Temp\mavenproject1-12058163025365783318.0-SNAPSHOT.jar was not recognized"

Comment: How do you try deploying it? How did you generate the jar file?